# SQL aggregation of data based on dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sure this is a very stupid question and I am having a dumb moment.
Consider the following basic scenario (this is a very small scenario compared with reality which has many many dimensions and measures):

[image: Data]

What I need to get to is the expected output.
So ALL costs between the input_Date and output_date defined in the params are included. However only the latest PID is included- defined as either:

1- where PIDs run sequentially, or overlap the latest one based on date_to as long as both aren't active at the @ output date
2- where there are two PID active at the @ output date show both

I can't for the life of me work out how to do this in SQL, note that is has to be non dynamic and not use any CTE unfortunately, just your basic SQL with subqueries

Obviously returning the necessary list of ID and PID is easy:

```
declare @input_date date ='2006-01-01'
declare @output_date date ='2006-12-31'

select a.PID, a.ID
from #tmp a
where date_from <=@output_date and date_to >=@input_date
```

But I can't figure out how to join this back to return the correct cost values

```
drop table tmp
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp](
       [date_from] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [date_to] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [ID] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
       [PID] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
       [cost] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT tmp VALUES('2005-1-1','2005-1-31','10001','X123',1254.32)
INSERT tmp VALUES('2000-10-10','2006-8-21','10005','TEST01',21350.9636378758)
INSERT tmp VALUES('2006-8-22','2099-12-31','10005','TEST02',22593.4926163943)
INSERT tmp VALUES('2006-1-1','2099-12-31','10006','X01',22458.3342354444)
INSERT tmp VALUES('2006-2-8','2099-12-31','10006','X02',22480.3772331959)
INSERT tmp VALUES('2006-1-1','2006-2-7','10007','AB01',565.416874152212)
INSERT tmp VALUES('2006-2-8','2006-7-31','10007','AA05',19108.3206482165)
```

I've made some progress using a CTE so you can see how I would do it this way if I could:

```
drop table #tmp 


CREATE TABLE #tmp (
       [date_from] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [date_to] [datetime] NOT NULL,
       [ID] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
       [PID] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
       [cost] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2005-1-1','2005-1-31','10001','X123',1254.32)
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2000-10-10','2006-8-21','10005','TEST01',21350.9636378758)
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2006-8-22','2099-12-31','10005','TEST02',22593.4926163943)
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2006-1-1','2099-12-31','10006','X01',22458.3342354444)
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2006-2-8','2099-12-31','10006','X02',22480.3772331959)
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2006-1-1','2006-2-7','10007','AB01',565.416874152212)
INSERT #tmp  VALUES('2006-2-8','2006-7-31','10007','AA05',19108.3206482165)

declare @input_date date ='2006-01-01'
declare @output_date date ='2006-12-31'


;with cte as (
select t.id,t.PID,t.cost,t.date_from,t.date_to , 
        iif(date_To >= @output_date  OR max_date_To is not null,PID,NULL) as PID2,
        b.total_id_cost 
    from #tmp  t
    left join (select ID,max(date_to) as max_date_to
                from #tmp
                where date_from <=@output_date and date_to >=@input_date
                group by ID) a
    on t.ID = a.ID and t.date_to = a.max_date_to
    left join (Select ID, sum(cost) as total_id_cost
                from  #tmp
                where date_from <=@output_date and date_to >=@input_date
                group by ID) b
    on t.ID = b.ID
    where date_from <=@output_date and date_to >=@input_date )


select distinct ID,PID2,
iif(ID in (
            select ID   
            from cte
            where PID2 IS NULL) 
and ID not in (select ID    
            from cte
            where PID IS NOT NULL
            group by ID
            having count (distinct PID2) >1  ), cte.total_id_cost, cost) as cost
from cte
where PID2 is not null;
```

Comment: What is the logic that determines what rows to show?

Comment: What makes a PID the "latest"?  date_from or date_to ?

Comment: Why the limitation of not using a cte? That is a rather arbitrary restraint.

Comment: Hi All,

Logic to show is: If the date_to is greater than @ input_date and is the latest PID record for the ID i.e. if the PID are sequential show only the latest, if they are running at the same time and the date_to >= @ output_date show both

CTE limitation is due to the interface unfortunately

Comment: What is your SQL version?

Comment: 2008 R2  I've edited the original post to try and add some clarity around what defines the latest PID

Comment: If you are writing your queries inside your application and it prevents things like cte it is time stop using pass through queries and start using stored procedures. That is a better approach anyway as it creates a layered approach.

Comment: I couldn't agree more but unfortunately it is out of my hands

Comment: For SQL 2008 recursive CTE will be one of fastest soultions. Without CTE you have to self join your table at least 4 times. Without CTE your solution will be very slow and ugly. Can you explain how CTE can affect interface?

Comment: Yes, the interface is an excel add in which connects to the DB via a WS. It uses a proprietary syntax which does not support a CTE.

I am well aware this would be a lot easier using a CTE or an SP and if I could, trust me I would be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so it looks like there's several problems to solve within 1 query.

1. We want the PID that matches the latest date. This wasn't too difficult and can be solved by joining the data with an aggregate of itself that finds the latest date
2. Where both PID is active i.e. overlapping from and to dates, then both must show. I found this to be more tricky. in the end I did a query to find the ones that do overlap and meet the dates, and did a count on that. then used this count as a criteria for the join on 1. so that it can conditionally pick the PID that matches the latest date

Then finally using the results from above, you can do the sum to get the cost. The resulting query is a bit of a monster, but here it is.
if it doesn't cover other scenarios not detailed, do let me know.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (date_from DATETIME, date_to DATETIME, ID INT, PID NVARCHAR(50), COST MONEY)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2005-1-1','2005-1-31','10001','X123',1254.32)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2000-10-10','2006-8-21','10005','TEST01',21350.9636378758)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2006-8-22','2099-12-31','10005','TEST02',22593.4926163943)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2006-1-1','2099-12-31','10006','X01',22458.3342354444)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2006-2-8','2099-12-31','10006','X02',22480.3772331959)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2006-1-1','2006-2-7','10007','AB01',565.416874152212)
INSERT @Data VALUES('2006-2-8','2006-7-31','10007','AA05',19108.3206482165)

declare @input_date date ='2006-01-01'
declare @output_date date ='2006-12-31'


select
    a.ID,
    PIDForMaxDateThatMatches.PID,
    SUM(a.cost) as cost
from
    @Data a
    inner join (
        -- number of PIDs for dates that overlap grouped by ID
        select
            a.ID,
            -- where there's no overlap then we want the count to be 1 so that later we can use it as condition
            COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(b.PID,'')) as NumberOfPID
        from
            @Data a
            -- may or may not find overlaps
            LEFT JOIN @data b ON
                b.date_from <=@output_date and
                b.date_to >=@input_date and
                a.date_from <= b.date_to and
                a.date_to >= b.date_from and
                a.ID = b.ID and
                a.PID <> b.PID
        where
            a.date_from <=@output_date and
            a.date_to >=@input_date
        group by
            a.ID) as PIDCountForOverlappingMatches ON
        a.ID = PIDCountForOverlappingMatches.ID
    left join (
        -- get the PID that matches the max date_to 
        select
            DataForMaxDate.ID,
            DataForMaxDate.date_from,
            DataForMaxDate.date_to,
            DataForMaxDate.PID
        from
            @Data as DataForMaxDate
            inner join (
                -- get the max date_to that matches the criteria
                select
                    ID,
                    MAX(date_to) as maxDateTo
                from
                    @Data a
                where
                    date_from <=@output_date and
                    date_to >=@input_date
                group by
                    ID) as MaxToDatePerID on
            DataForMaxDate.ID = MaxToDatePerID.ID and
            DataForMaxDate.date_to = MaxToDatePerID.maxDateTo) as PIDForMaxDateThatMatches on
        a.ID = PIDForMaxDateThatMatches.ID AND
        -- if there's no overlapping dates the PID count would be 1, which we'll take the PID that matches the max(date_to)
        -- but if there is overlap, then we want both dates to show, thus the from date must also match before we take the PID
        (PIDCountForOverlappingMatches.NumberOfPID = 1 OR a.date_from = PIDForMaxDateThatMatches.date_from)

where
    a.date_from <= @output_date and
    a.date_to >= @input_date
GROUP BY
    a.ID,
    PIDForMaxDateThatMatches.PID
ORDER BY
    a.ID
```

EDIT: DB Fiddle http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d43cb4b9765da1bca035531e78a2c77d

Results:
ID      PID     cost
10005   TEST02  43944.4562
10006   X01     22458.3342
10006   X02     22480.3772
10007   AA05    19673.7375

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work great... now to attempt to scale it up!

Comment: I have found an example where it doesn't work as the second line comes back as a null. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=d35fd72293ad6b4dab18593a97945fb8

Comment: Hi Adam, 
What is your expected results on the new scenario?

Comment: Hi Henry, I was just trying to work that out myself! It’s ID 10007 which is the problem, I believe the whole amount should be showing against the one PID (AB01) in this case as the other two are dated before the end date. I hadn’t really considered this scenario until he live data threw it out

Comment: ah ok, in that case I'd break the original query up, instead of conditionally matching, do 2 left joins on the same set, 1 to cover the date overlapm other to cover max date when no overlap. 
Here's the DB Fiddle http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9ef84b21d0d035723bb153d122348148

Comment: You are a magician sir... I've just come up with another hypothetical but I actually have no idea how this should be treated, where the ID has two historical PID and two active PID... The only thing I can think of is to randomly allocate the values to one of the two active ones... http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f00fe6efc86d630d07d3d4d8052b08b2

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can try the following query :

`select a.resource_id ID, max(a.post_id) PID, SUM(a.cost) Cost
from #tmp a
where date_from <=@output_date and date_to >=@input_date
group by a.resource_id
order by a.resource_id;`

Comment: Ok given this scenario it works, however if the latest PID didn't happen to be the max PID, then it would fail would it not? I have edited the data as an example

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by Latest PID ?

Comment: I thought it was the max

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID, 
    q1.PID, 
    SUM(t1.cost)
FROM
 Table AS t1
JOIN
(
SELECT
    q2.ID,
    t2.PID
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ID, 
        MAX(date_to) AS maxdate
    FROM
        Table
    GROUP BY
        ID
    ) AS q2
JOIN
    table AS t2
ON
    q2.ID = t2.ID
AND 
    q2.maxdate = t2.date_to
) AS q1
ON
    t1.ID = q1.ID
AND
    t1.PID = q1.PID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID, 
    q1.PID
```

Comment: Unfortunately not I am afraid. I've added the scheme and data to the OP so you can test!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query without CTE. Idea of query:

1) Find consecutive dates and make different groups within each `id`

2) Find min and max date, sum of costs for each group

3) Limit by input parametres

```
declare @date_from date = '20060101'
declare @date_to date = '20061231'

declare @myTable table(
    date_from date
    , date_to date
    , id int
    , pid varchar(30)
    , cost decimal(10,2)
)
insert into @myTable values
    ('20050101', '20050201', 10001, 'x123', 1254.32)
    , ('20001010', '20060821', 10005, 'test01', 21350.96)
    , ('20060822', '20991231', 10005, 'test02', 22593.49)
    , ('20060101', '20991231', 10006, 'x01', 22548.33)
    , ('20060208', '20991231', 10006, 'x02', 22480.38)
    , ('20060101', '20060207', 10007, 'abo1', 565.42)
    , ('20060208', '20060731', 10007, 'abo2', 19108.32)

select
    date_from = min(date_from), date_to = max(date_to)
    , id, pid = max(case when date_to = max_date_to then pid end)
    , cost = sum(cost)
from (
    select
        a.date_from, a.date_to, a.id, a.pid, a.cost, a.rn, grp = sum(b.ss)
        , max_date_to = max(a.date_to) over (partition by a.id, sum(b.ss))
    from
        (
            select
                a.*, ss = case when datediff(dd, b.date_to, a.date_from) = 1 then 0 else 1 end
            from
                (
                    select
                        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by date_from)
                    from
                        @myTable
                ) a
                left join (
                    select
                        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by date_from)
                    from
                        @myTable
                ) b on a.id = b.id and a.rn - 1 = b.rn
        ) a
        left join (
            select
                a.*, ss = case when datediff(dd, b.date_to, a.date_from) = 1 then 0 else 1 end
            from
                (
                    select
                        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by date_from)
                    from
                        @myTable
                ) a
                left join (
                    select
                        *, rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by date_from)
                    from
                        @myTable
                ) b on a.id = b.id and a.rn - 1 = b.rn
        ) b on a.id = b.id and a.rn >= b.rn
    group by a.date_from, a.date_to, a.id, a.pid, a.cost, a.rn
) t
group by id, grp, max_date_to
having min(date_from) <= @date_from and max(date_to) >= @date_to
order by id
```

Output

```
date_from   date_to     id      pid     cost
------------------------------------------------
2000-10-10  2099-12-31  10005   test02  43944.45
2006-01-01  2099-12-31  10006   x01     22548.33
```

Result is a bit different than your provided output. But:

1) For `id = 10006` and `pid = X02` `date_from = 08/02/2006` while input is `01/01/2006`

2) For `id = 10007` `date_to = 31/07/2006` while input is `31/12/2006`

So, I think query works correctly

[Rextester demo](http://rextester.com/MGI73117) in more readable format with cte

Comment: Hi Uzi, thank you for this! However both of the exclusions that you mention should be included. The output I provided is what is required from the query

Comment: Hi. I thought you were looking for data that fully covers your input parametres. But looks like you are looking for overlapping intervals. Then just change `having` clause in my query to `having min(date_from) <= @date_to and max(date_to) >= @date_from`. You will get your expected result. Just for performance issues